# I can't change a global variable value of javascript using a function

Tags: javascript

```
function just(chap_id)
{
    alert(chap_id);
    chapter_name = (document.getElementById(chap_id).name = document.getElementById((chap_id.replace( "i", "t" ))).innerHTML);
    <%= chapter_select = 1 %>
}
```

I've called this function in an `onclick` event.`chapter_name` is a global variable.when i use alert to view the variable value outside the function,i found that the variable value had not changed.Any idea to change value inside a function

Comment: To be clear, you have declared it as `var chapter_name;` in a higher scope than this function?

Comment: It would help if we could see all the code related to `chapter_name`. You can certainly change global variables from inside functions: see e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/KFMkA/

Comment: What do you expect to happen ? You are currently assiging the result of assigning a value to something

Comment: no any other code is attached with chap_id..it is just used to get the id of the div element.

Comment: i expect that the value of the variable must be changed when i use it outside the function just(chap_id)

Comment: *"when i use alert to view the variable value outside the function"*... I have the feeling you are calling `alert` before the value changed or `just` throws an error for some reason. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: This seems very jumbled.  Do you really mean to set both the name of the element you find and the chapter_name variable to the innerHTML of an element with a similar id (except that "i" has been replaced by "t")?  Because that's what it looks to be doing.

Comment: @user1512051: sorry, I should have said all the code related to `chapter_name` (I’ve edited my original comment now). Your problem isn’t related specifically to setting the value of a global variable from within a function, as that works fine: see http://jsfiddle.net/KFMkA/

Comment: Moreover, what is the <% ... %> stuff doing in there?  Leftover PHP/ASP?

Comment: no i'm using it after the function code runs..but the alert is displayed before the onclick event runs..

Comment: @ScottSauyet no it just replaces the id as "t1" if it is originally "i1"..

Comment: it is just used to declare a java variable when onclick event of a particular div element occurs.@ScottSauyet

Comment: @user1512051: *“the alert is displayed before the onclick event runs”* — if you’re calling the function that changes `chapter_name` in an `onclick`, then if you alert the value of `chapter_name` before the onclick has run, you’ll still see the old value of `chapter_name`.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite it is possible in call of a function..but not in an onclick event..

Comment: @user1512051 You have to call the `alert` after the `onclick` event has been *triggered* to witness any possible value change. Assuming `onclick="just('t1')"`, try `onclick="just('t1'); alert(chapter_name);"`

Comment: @PaulD.Waite ya..got it..so the script is completely run and then only the onclick event occurs.am i right

Comment: So as I read the code, if you call `just("i42")`, it will look for the element with id `t42`, find its innerHTML (say, "theAnswer"), and then assign the `name` property of the element with id `i42` as well as `chapter_name` to "theAnswer".  Is that the expected behavior?  What if there is no `t42`?  Or no `i42`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski i called a function to display an alert of the variable and it works..

Comment: @user1512051: I’m not quite sure what you’re asking. The onclick event occurs when you click (i.e. mousedown and mouseup) on an element. Any function assigned to the onclick event of that element will then run. I’ve updated my example to show that changing a global variable from a function assigned to an onclick event works: see http://jsfiddle.net/KFMkA/1/